# Adding item from one tableview to another from selection(JAVAFX)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have products in one product-table that loads on start, from that table I want to add the select item from the first tableview to the cart-table.

So here is the problem, I know how to add a selected item from one table to another. But, if item already exists in a table it should increase the quantity and not add a duplicate row.
I've tried a couple of ways that kinda works except they always have bugs.

The logic is under `addButton()`.

```java
public class OrderController implements Initializable {

    OrderRepository or = new OrderRepository();
    ShoeRepository sr = new ShoeRepository();

    LogInController logInController = new LogInController();
    private int customer_ID;
    private int total;
    private List<ProductCart> productCarts = new LinkedList<>();

    @FXML
    private Label label_total;

    @FXML
    private Button button_makeOrder;
    @FXML
    private Button button_add;
    @FXML
    private Button button_remove;
    @FXML
    private TableView<ProductCart> table_cart;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Product> tableProduct;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> col_shoe;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> col_brand;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> col_color;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Integer> col_size;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Integer> col_price;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Integer> col_stock;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ProductCart, String> col_cart_Shoe;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ProductCart, String> col_cart_brand;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ProductCart, String> col_cart_color;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ProductCart, Integer> col_cart_size;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ProductCart, Integer> col_cart_price;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ProductCart, Integer> col_cart_quantity;

    public void a() {
        System.out.println(customer_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        col_shoe.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("shoeName"));
        col_brand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("shoeBrand"));
        col_color.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("shoeColor"));
        col_size.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("shoeSize"));
        col_price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("shoePrice"));
        col_stock.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stock"));

        col_cart_Shoe.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        col_cart_brand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("brand"));
        col_cart_color.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("color"));
        col_cart_size.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("size"));
        col_cart_price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        col_cart_quantity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
        getProducts();
        tableProduct.setItems(observableList);
        customer_ID = logInController.getCustomer_ID();
    }

    ObservableList<Product> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<ProductCart> observableListC = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    public void getProducts() {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Shoe> shoes = sr.getAllShoes();

        shoes.forEach(shoe -> products.add(new Product(shoe.getShoe_ID(), shoe.getName(), shoe.getBrand().getName(),
                shoe.getColor().getName(), shoe.getShoeSize().getShoeSize(), shoe.getInStock().getStock(),
                shoe.getPrice().getPrice())));

        products.forEach(product -> observableList.add(product));
    }

    public int getCustomer_ID() {
        return customer_ID;
    }

    public void addButton() {

        Product product = tableProduct.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        ProductCart productCart = new ProductCart(product.getID(), product.getShoeName(), product.getShoeBrand(), product.getShoeColor(),
                product.getShoeSize(),1, product.getShoePrice());
        System.out.println(productCart.getName());

        for (ProductCart item: productCarts) {
            if (item.getName().equals(productCart.getName())) {
                item.setQuantity(item.getQuantity() + 1);
                table_cart.getItems().clear();
                observableListC.remove(item);
                observableListC.add(item);
            }
            else {
                productCarts.add(item);
                observableListC.add(item);
            }
        }
        table_cart.setItems(observableListC);
        updateTotal();

    }

    public void removeButton() {

    }

    public void makeOrder() {

    }

    public void updateTotal() {
        total = 0;
        List<ProductCart> productCarts = table_cart.getItems();
        productCarts.forEach(productCart -> total += productCart.getPrice());
        label_total.setText(total+"");
    }
}
```

Changing only the quantity and stock in the tables works a lot better now.
However once an item is added to the table, adding the same row seems impossible without any bugs for me.

Version 1: Adding quantity to the existing row, unable to add new rows of other producs

Version 2: Being able to add rows, disables the ability to add quantity to existing row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYoJ3.png

```java
public void addButton() {
    ProductCart productCart;
    Product product = tableProduct.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    productCart = new ProductCart(product.getID(), product.getShoeName(), product.getShoeBrand(),
    product.getShoeColor(), product.getShoeSize(), product.getSold()+1, product.getShoePrice());

    if (product.getStock() != 0) {
        table_cart.getItems().add(productCart);
    }
    updateStock();
    updateTotal();
}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: and [mcve] please ..

Comment: still not an [mcve] :) That said: why don't you simple increase the quantity of the ProductCart when it is already in the cart? (vs creating a new one with increased quantity and remove/add the old/new, respectively)

Comment: I think a product should have a unique ID. That way before you add any product, you can check to see if the other table already contains that ID. The other way is to implement the equals method in the product object. If the other table already contains the product then do something different.

Comment: Objects already have IDs, but hidden. Don't want to show the IDs to the user since the same IDs from the database.